# How to firgure out if a set of vectors represent lines, planes or hyperplanes?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

if i am given a span of, let's say 3 vectors, what would be a way to determine if they represented a line, plane or a hyperplane? i have reduced siad vectors to reduced row echelon form, but don't see how that helps me. searching online also doesn't lead me to any results where they deal with this problem using vertical matrices. any help/ clue would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing calculations won't help you understand the concept. Insight will. (Calculation helps you get to the insight).

A line is dimension $1$. This means the rank is $1$. This means there is one linearly independent eigenvector and adding another to the set makes it dependent. In your case, add 2.

What can we say about planes and hyperplanes, now?

Comment: hmm. we aren't yet introduced to the concept of eigenvector yet.

Comment: but does it mean that plane and hyperplanes would have ranks of 2 and 3 respectively?

Comment: ok. after doing some problems, i have observed that lines have rank of 1, planes have rank of 2, and hyperplanes have rank of 3. it this correct? could someone confirm this?

Comment: What is the definition of hyperplane? If you mean 3-dimensional space, you are correct - but remember, we call them bases - so we have bases with rank 1 define lines, bases with rank 2 define planes, etc.

Comment: what if it was 6 dimensional space, like vectors in r6? would the rank have to be >= 3 in order for vectors to represent a hyperplane?

Comment: Necessarily. The name is just a name, not a definition.

Comment: There is a type of algebra called Grassmann Algebra, which builds in the concept of linear dependence, and with which you can calculate systematically geometric results with objects of various dimensions or "grades", such as independence, intersections, projections, perpendicularity, inside/outside regions etc. This might interest you sometime in the future.